# Where should I save variable of pressed key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an React application with resize component. I want to keep height x width ratio, when a shift key is pressed. Where should I save `isShiftPressed` value. Can I save it to `window` object (`window.isShiftPressed = false`), or is there any better way? Or since I am using React should I save it to some component and give this information with props?

Comment: what is the user doing to resize? using mouse with drag? arrow keys, button click, etc? Might be a better solution than storing a variable.

Comment: @epascarello Similar to Photoshop or other graphic editors - Mouse with drag.

Comment: So it is in the event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey so there is zero need for a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to save the shift status at all. Some keys are passed to a mouse event as well.

See this example:

```js
const statusElm = document.querySelector( '.shift-status' );
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', ( e ) => {
  statusElm.innerText = e.shiftKey ? 'yes' : 'no';
} );
```

```html
<p>Move mouse around to update shift status.</p>
<p>Shift pressed? <span class="shift-status">no</span></p>
```

If you really want to save the state of your shift key, convert your current React component to a class, so it can hold a state.

With the following solution, the shift key is always up to date (iframe needs to have focus to work though).

```js
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.state = {
      shiftPressed: false,
      mousePos: [ 0, 0 ],
    };
    
    this.updateShiftState = this.updateShiftState.bind(this);
    this.updateMouseMovement = this.updateMouseMovement.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener( 'keydown', this.updateShiftState );
    document.addEventListener( 'keyup', this.updateShiftState );
    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', this.updateMouseMovement );
  }
  
  componentWillUnMount() {
    document.removeEventListener( 'keydown', this.updateShiftState );
    document.removeEventListener( 'keyup', this.updateShiftState );
    document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', this.updateMouseMovement );
  }
  
  updateShiftState( e ) {
    this.setState( {
      shiftPressed: e.shiftKey,
    } );
  }
  
  updateMouseMovement( e ) {
    this.setState( {
      shiftPressed: e.shiftKey,
      mousePos: [ ( e.screenX || e.clientX ), ( e.screenY || e.clientY ) ],
    } );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Wrapper">
        Shift pressed: { this.state.shiftPressed ? 'yes' : 'no' }<br />
        Mouse pos: { JSON.stringify( this.state.mousePos ) }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Wrapper />, document.getElementById( 'app' ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: It's working in React as well. (I just use the `e.shiftKey` part)